# sudoku number of solutions with no recusion

Tags: algorithms

am asking you if you know if it's possible that sudoku, which is able to be solved with no recusion (with  intersection of sets only) has more than one solution ?

Thank you for answering me!

Comment: Could you be clearer? It is technically not a Sudoku puzzle if it has more than one solution.

Comment: Sudoku with multiply solutions, why not ? I'm intrested in if there is only one solution if it's possible to solve with intersection only.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25701701/781723, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/921460/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, let me cite Wikipedia's article [Sudoku](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudoku):

> The puzzle setter provides a partially completed grid, which for a well-posed puzzle has a unique solution.

So, let's assume we are trying to fill a partially completed grid, following the rules of Sudoku. If I understand the question, then you are trying to fill the grid only by making conclusions like

> Entry where the first line and the first row intersect, is empty. In the first line, there are already numbers from $1$ to $7$. On the other hand, there are numbers from $2$ to $8$ in the first row.  Therefore, the missing number must be number $9$.

If you want to solve the grid *without recursion*, you must always have at least one empty place with only one possible entry. Write the only possible number in that entry and repeat procedure. You will solve the puzzle and your solution is the only one, since at every step you have made, you had no choice.

Comment: Yes, am aware of that. So am wondering is it possbile that if i start solving at AxA cell or at IxI cell the solutions won't be the same ?

Comment: @user2988171 (Assume $1\leq A,I\leq 9$) You have to start solving at one of the cells where there is only one possible entry . If there are two such cells ($A\times A$ where $4$ is the only option and $I\times I$ where $8$ is the only option), and you start at $A\times A$, after that, number $8$ is still the only option for cell $I\times I$, provided at least one solution of your *sudoku* exists.

Comment: yes,yes but if there are two cells where only one is possible. Is it possible to get two different solutions at the end ? Depends on where you start solving (at first one possibility cell or at second)

Comment: @user2988171: Perhaps the contrapositive here is easier to understand: if there are two solutions to a "sudoku puzzle", then you can not solve it by set intersections. As Antoine is saying, when solving by set intersections one only writes a number when there is precisely one possibility. Thus this clearly can't be solved by sets when there are two possible solutions.

Comment: Alright my friend. So it's impossible to get two different solutions with using set intersections? where ever you start solving it ?

Comment: @RghtHndSd But what if starting in the cell magically cancels out different possibilities as starting in the other? (I am just trying to wear user2988171's shous).

Comment: @Antoine: Another way to say "magically cancel out different possibilities" is "logically eliminate a valid solution". Another way to say "logically eliminate a valid solution" is  "make an error".

Comment: @RghtHndsd Well said. ATuser2988171 **First step:** fill all the squares with only one possible entry. At this step, you have on choice. The numbers in these cells are completely determined by starting numbers. So ... it is the same if you are given the starting grid or the grid after the step one. These two grids have the same solutions. **Step two:** fill all the new squares with only one possible entry ...

Comment: @Antoine: I get the feeling that user2988171 is not concerned with understanding why this is true, they only want to know that it is true. user2988171: My apologies if this is incorrect.

Comment: @RghtHndSd We are completely agreed on this. And I wonder if he has at least read my answer where I explicitly said how many solutions are there.

Comment: Thank you, this is what i was intrested in. Only one posible solution can be at sudoku if it's possbile to be solved with  intersection of sets only.

Comment: @user2988171 May I ask why are you interested in the number of solutions?

Comment: I am writing a program for solving sudokus, first i try with intersection, on fail i start with recursion of intersections. I find all solutions with recursion, but i wasn't sure of intersection at first step.